# Isovalue in Matlab's Isosurface

Tags: matlab, graphics, plot, geometry-surface

As I read the Matlab help, the `isosurface()` takes the form of

```
fv = isosurface(V,isovalue)
```

`V` is the volume data,

I think a `isosurface` should plot the surface have the value of `isovalue`. However, as I tried myself, it looks like Matlab plots all the points with `value > isovalue`.

This is so confusing. Is this `isovalue` actually a threshold value?!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`isosurface` does no plotting. It computes the isosurface geometry some data at the given isovalue.

The output contains the faces and verticies of the isosurface that can be passed directly to `patch`.

You should do `help isosurface` for an explanation as well as two examples on how it's used.

You'll have to include more code for more help, since you can't possibly be plotting anything with the command that you wrote.